# Can I specify where and aggregate simultaneously in python-eve?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, where-clause, eve

I know python-eve supports [aggregation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#mongodb-aggregation-framework) and [filtering](http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering). I know how to use them separately:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/posts?aggregate={"$value": 2}
http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people?where={"lastname": "Doe"}
```

But the question is: Can I use them simultaneously?

For example, I have defined an endpoint like:

```
posts = {
    'datasource': {
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {"$unwind": "$tags"},
                {"$group": {"_id": "$tags", "count": {"$sum": "$value"}}},
                {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can I use a query URL like:

```
http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people?where={"lastname": "Doe"}&aggregate={"$value": 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **YES** but you need to define the filtering in aggregation with `$match` command. The `filter` keys in `data_source` doesn't accept parameters from url.

For example,

`things_recommended = {
    'url': 'things/recommended/',
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'things',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {"$match": {"id":"$id"}},
                {"$lookup": {
                                "from": "other_collection",
                                "localField": "localField",
                                "foreignField": "foreignField",
                                "as": "some_field"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}`

The query url is like

`some_url/things/recommended?aggregate={"$id": 1}`

Note you need to use `encoderUrlComponent` and `JSON.stringfy` to escape the characters in this url.

You can even pass the whole match criterion:

`things_recommended = {
    'url': 'things/recommended/',
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'things',
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {"$match": "$where$},
                {"$lookup": {
                                "from": "other_collection",
                                "localField": "localField",
                                "foreignField": "foreignField",
                                "as": "some_field"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}`

The query url is like

`some_url/things/recommended?aggregate={"$where": {"$or": [{"family": "$family_id"}, {"is_shared": True}]}}`

Note you need to use `encoderUrlComponent` and `JSON.stringfy` to escape the characters in this url.

I have tested on my computer and it works.